# ethereum - call and delegatecall not working

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;
contract D {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;

  function callSetN(address _e, uint256 _n) public {
    _e.call(abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("setN(uint256)")), _n)); 
  }


  function delegatecallSetN(address _e, uint _n) public {
    _e.delegatecall(abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("setN(uint256)")), _n));
  }
}

contract E {
  uint public n;
  uint public test;
  address public sender;

  function setN(uint256 _n) public {
    n = _n;
  }
}
```

That's my 2 example contracts. I am trying to understand call and delegatecall.

**Problem 1:** When I call `callSetN` in contract D and pass contract E's address and number: 20, it seems like that E contract's `setN` function gets called, but `n` variable doesn't become 20 in contract E.

**Problem 2:** When I call `delegatecallSetN` in contract D and pass contract E's address and number: 20, it still calls that function, but now, `D` contract's variable `n` doesn't become 20. Also at some point, I realized that for this one, `setN` doesn't called called at all.

**Problem 3:** I am starting to wonder why I'd need to use `delegateCall` in my code at all ? `call` seems enough and sufficient. Any example ?

Both of the problems seem to be related to how badly I use `encode` and `_n` variable.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `abi.encode()` adds padding the its arguments. The results is it is calling E fallback function which does nothing.

It can be resolved by using `abi.encodeWithSignature()`:

```
  function callSetN(address _e, uint256 _n) public {
    _e.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("setN(uint256)", _n)); 
  }


  function delegatecallSetN(address _e, uint _n) public {
    _e.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("setN(uint256)", _n));
  }
```

Comment: Awesome Ismael... Works fine after that...

Comment: Hey Ismael, Unfortunatelly, something is still wrong.  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90917/delegate-call-msg-sender-wrong-value  please read the answers and my comments and you will realize it