# delegate call - msg.sender wrong value

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;
contract D {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;

  function delegatecallSetN(address _e, uint _n) public {
    _e.delegatecall(abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("setN(uint256)")), _n));
  }
}

contract E {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;
  uint test = 10;

  function setN(uint256 _n) public {
    n = _n;
    sender = msg.sender;
  }
}
```

Question 1:

I have this contract. Now, when I call a `delegatecallSetN` from remix with the address of E, it successfully calls E contract's `setN` function.  as we know how `delegatecall` works, it sets my passed `_n` value on D contract. Now, what about `sender` value on D contract ? It still is 0x000000...000 . Why doesn't it set `msg.sender` on it ?

---

Question 2:

Let's say in contract E's `setN` function, I add `test = 50`. As we know, the code of `setN` will be executed in the context of Contract D which doesn't have `test` variable at all. Why doesn't it result in exception or error at all and why does the transaction still succeed ?

UPDATED CODE:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

contract D {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;


  function delegatecallSetN(address _e, uint _n) public {
    _e.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("setN(uint256)", _n));
  }
  
  
}

contract E {
  uint public n;
  uint public test;
  address public sender;

  function setN(uint256 _n) public {
    n = _n;
    sender = msg.sender;
    test = 20;
  }
}
```

Comment: After modifying the code to use `abi.encodeWithSignature` it works as expected both `n` and `sender` are updated correctly for `D`. Regarding question 2) the variables at contract level are referenced by a storage slot at compile time, since slots always exists you cannot check during runtime if a variable was defined or not.

Comment: Question 1) It doesn't work even after I change it to `abi.encodeWithSignature`, I am going to include the remix code in my updated question and you can test it too. Basically `n` variable of D contract gets set, but not the `sender`. I just tested and `sender` became 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000014 this address. which doesn't seem right. Question 2) I still don't understand your answer for the Question 2 unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For delegatecall to work correctly both contracts should have compatible storage layout. Having the same variables in the same order. If variables are reordered the storage layout will be incompatible and it will not work as expected.

---

The compiler assigns storage slots in the same order the variables are defined.

```
contract D {
  uint public n;              // <-- slot 0
  address public sender       // <-- slot 1
```

and

```
contract E {
  uint public n;              // <-- slot 0
  uint public test;           // <-- slot 1
  address public sender;      // <-- slot 2
```

When contract E modifies `sender` it modifies slot 2, similarly for `n` it modifies slot 0 and for `test` slot 1.

- `n` has the same slot in D and E so its modification by E will be reflected in D.
- `sender` for E has slot 2, so any modification is not visible from D because there's no variable assigned slot 2.
- `test` has slot 1 for E, so it will store `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014` in slot 1. For D slot 1 is `sender` an address so it will interpret as `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000014`.

Comment: Ismael, you rock big time ! Thank you, finally it makes sense. Question 1) I am not sure when it's really a good idea to use `delegetecall` since if you use it, then you should also have compatible storage layouts figured out in advance.  for `selfdestruct` , that would be a good idea, but can't think of anything else. Question 2) so, in contract D, if I use assembly and read from slot 2, i will still have the variable msg.sender stored in it, right ?

Comment: Yes, with assembly you can read any slot you want. Proxy contracts use delegatecall https://blog.openzeppelin.com/proxy-patterns/.

Answer (score 0):

**About Question 1:**

The state of `contract E` is not getting updated, because your deletecall in `contract D` is not working.

Replace:

`_e.delegatecall(abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("setN(uint256)")), _n));`

with

`(bool success,) = address(_e).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("setN(uint256)", _n));`

**About question 2:**

I got a bit confused, when you're making delegatecall from `contract D` to `contract E`, you're referring to method `setN` and now inside this method you can access the state of contract where this method is defined ( `contract E` ). I don't see where is the issue here, that's how it should be working.

Comment: question 1) Sorry, I placed the wrong code there, even if I change it with encodeWithSignature like you did, the problem is still there. imagine I have your code and read the first question again.

Question 2) when I call delegatecall from D, setN function gets called, but it's like that whatever is written in setN function gets called in contract D's context. That's how it should be working, but if I add test = 20 in setN function, when this function gets called in context of D, it should throw an exception, because contract D doesn't have test storage variable

Comment: You're doing something wrong. https://pastebin.com/g0ZB5Ku4 This is my code and the call is working great.

Comment: we are talking about delegatecall and not call.

Comment: My bad, I should've explained a bit more. When using ```delegatecall``` the storage still refer to the calling contract, but when using ```call``` like in my example the storage of the called contract is getting updated. If you want your logic to work as described in the question just use ```(bool success,) = address(_e).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("setN(uint256)", _n));```. In general both ```call``` and ```delegatecall``` are low level functions that returns bool. You can validate this bool to check if the call was successful. Please select this answer as the answer if it helped you.