# truffle - should I remember the results of previous calls?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract

I wrote a smart contract. now, I am writing tests in truffle .

the code is gonna look like this.

```
contract('contract', accounts => {
  it("test1", () => {

  })


  it("test2", () => {
    
  })

  it("test3", () => {
    
  })
  
})
```

Now, let's say I transferred 30 coins from accounts[1] to accounts[2] in `test1` and in `test1`, I had a check for that and it asserted well. Now, in `test2`, I am testing different function, but that function still relies on the balance of accounts[1]. Now, it means that I should know what the balance was after the `test1` ran. This is still fine, but then, in `test3`, I should know what the balance was for accounts[1] after `test2` was run.

**Problem 1:** if some other developer comes and looks at this file, he can't really change something in `test3`, because if so, then he really has to know the results of accouns[1] from `test2` which implies that he has to know results from `test1`. So, He has to understand everything..

**Problem 2:** If we decide that each `it` test of mocha is not dependent on each other, that means that, for each test, we should put each test in `contract('contract')` in order for truffle to start redeploying from scratch for each test. This is too time consuming and also,  each test will become TOO BIG. because now, `test3` should include all the functions from solidity contract while in Problem 1, it would only have to include the function that it's going to test and `test2` would take care of the previous dependent functions.

What's your recommendation ? or what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Truffle tests are based on mocha framework so you can use similar approach.

- Create multiple `contract` sections for the same contract. Each test will be independent.

  ```
  contract('token - balances', () => { ... })

  contract('token - transfers', () => { ... })

  contract('token - minting', () => { ... })
  ```
- Use tests fixtures `before`, `after`, `beforeEach`, `afterEach` to customize tests. For example you can initialize your contracts on `before` and then reset to known state at `beforeEach` so the next test will have a predictable starting point.

  ```
  contract('token - balances', () => {
    before(() => {
      // Execute once before all tests
    })

    afterEach(() => {
      // Execute every time after each test
    })

    it('test1', () => {
    })
  });
  ```

Comment: Great answer! If you are only testing against ganache, you can use `evm_snapshot` and `evm_revert` in your `beforeEach` and `afterEach` to reset state in between each test.